# Print %YAML <version> on output`s header

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, yaml

This is the code:

```
file '/etc/myproduct/myfile.yaml' do
  content node['myproduct']['config'].to_hash.to_yaml( :UseVersion => true, :UseHeader => true )
  mode 0644
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
end
```

output:

```
---
vars:
address-groups:
```

Im trying to add %YAML 1.1 above --- so it will look like this:

```
%YAML 1.1
---
vars:
address-groups:
```

also tried *to_yaml* only - no good.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just do it the brute-force way:

```
content "%YAML 1.1\n" + node['myproduct']['config'].to_hash.to_yaml
```

I'm sure there is a better way, but that works so ... :)

Comment: First of all - thanks! its working! i had more 'ugly' ideas in mind, thought maybe there are more legit ways.. im happy with ur way, but more is welcome.